# Wordpress | adding a blog link to the navigation menu

Tags: wordpress

I have this wordpress website, and it contains some articles, i need to create a button to the navigation menu that is labelled "Blog" that leads to all the articles, how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

1. You should have a page named "Blog".
2. Go to your "Settings" tab, then "Reading" and set your "Posts page"
   to the "Blog" page.
3. Add your "Blog" page to your menu under "Appearance" then "Menus"

Source for Blog info: http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-create-a-separate-page-for-blog-posts-in-wordpress/

Source for Menu info: https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Menu_User_Guide